# tokio spawn_blocking error when 3rd party code is not thread safe

Tags: rust, blocking, rust-tokio, testcontainers

I am trying to create a test container in `[tokio::test]`,

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
    use testcontainers::*;
    use anyhow::Result;
    use tokio::task;
    use testcontainers::images::postgres::Postgres;

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn test_pg_store() -> Result<()> {
        let docker = Arc::new(Mutex::new(clients::Cli::default()));
        let _node = task::spawn_blocking(move || {
            let pg = Postgres::default();
            let c = docker.lock().unwrap().run(pg);
            Arc::new(Mutex::new(c))
        }).await?;

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

`docker.run(pg);` is likely to take seconds so I need to use `spawn_blocking`.
However, got the error

```
error[E0277]: `(dyn core::container::Docker + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> access/src/store/postgres.rs:40:42
    |
40  |           let _node = task::spawn_blocking(move || {
    |  _____________________--------------------_^
    | |                     |
    | |                     required by a bound introduced by this call
41  | |             let pg = Postgres::default();
42  | |             let c = docker.lock().unwrap().run(pg);
43  | |             Arc::new(Mutex::new(c))
44  | |         }).await?;
    | |_________^ `(dyn core::container::Docker + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `Send` is not implemented for `(dyn core::container::Docker + 'static)`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Send` for `Unique<(dyn core::container::Docker + 'static)>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Box<(dyn core::container::Docker + 'static)>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Container<'_, Postgres>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Sync` for `std::sync::Mutex<Container<'_, Postgres>>`
    = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Send` for `std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<Container<'_, Postgres>>>`
```

Test container is a 3rd party library which I don't have much control. I wonder how to deal with such cases when using `tokio`.
Simply wrapping things into `Arc` and `Mutex` does not work.

Comment: `Arc` does not, but `Mutex` should.

Comment: Do you need to return the container from `spawn_blocking`? Currently it isn't used.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman
Adding Mutex does not work either

Comment: Oh it is `Send`, I thought it is `Sync`. Well I don't have time to dig into that, but usually in those cases you don't really have something to do besides spawning on the same thread or investigating why it isn't `Send`.

Comment: Sounds like the best solution would be to [`block_in_place`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.block_in_place.html)

Comment: The `block_in_place` method only works on multi-threaded runtimes, which may move tasks across threads. Since the value is not Send, it cannot exist inside a task in a multi-threaded runtime.